# Instructions conversion from SSE to ARM Neon

Tags: arm, sse, neon, intrinsics

I'm trying to convert a piece of code in from SSE to ARM Neon for optimization. For most of the SSE instructions of the code I found some clearly equivalent Neon ones. I've got some problems  with these though:

```
result1_shifted = _mm_srli_si128 (result1, 1);

result=_mm_packus_epi16 (res1,res2);

_mm_storeu_si128 (p_dest, result);
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: This kind of 1:1 translation of SIMD intrinsics doesn't work very well for SSE -> Neon - you really need to go back to a scalar reference implementation and then implement that in Neon from scratch. Often there's a better approach that's more suited to the available instructions/intrinsics.

Comment: Could you please give me some more specific information on how to do that? I've never done this and I only need to convert few instructions but I'm really struggling.Thank you.

Comment: Do it in two stages: (1) reverse engineer the SSE code into scalar form (i.e. just straight C code), then test/benchmark/profile it to (a) make sure it works correctly and (b) determine whether there really is a performance hot spot that needs to be optimised; then (2) if (1b) indicates that the code needs to be optimised then you will need to go through the Neon learning curve and implement the code using Neon SIMD intrinsics or assembler. Ideally you want to avoid (2) if possible.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the comments that it's probably a good idea to go back to a "C" (or anything really) reference design and maybe start from scratch.  In particular you will find that perhaps NEON has some more optimal ways of doing things in some cases.  But if you find that you need to do nearly identical things, here are some hints:

`_mm_srli_si128 (result1, 1);` Try [VEXT.S8](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/CIHGAEFI.html) Qdst, Qsrc, Qsrc2, #1, where src2 has been cleared to 0.

`_mm_packus_epi16 (res1,res2);` Try [VQMOVN.S16](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/CIHFJICE.html) Ddst, Qsrc.  The key word when looking for alternatives is "narrow."  You are moving with narrowing.  "Q" is NEON nomenclature for saturation. You may have an issue because you are doing signed to unsigned, which I'm not sure NEON supports, but your use case may be okay, but that's why having reference and tests is good!

`_mm_storeu_si128 (__m128i *p, __m128i a);` Obviously there is [VSTM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/CIHEIIGI.html) and there are lots of options here. You probably want to look at this in some detail.